# Creating mysql index failed on amazon RDS mysql table

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I was trying to create index for a 100million rows table on a datatime type field called updated_date. My clause is: create index ops_index_updated on ops_data(updated_date);
But I met the following problem: 
lERROR 1034 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table 'ops_data'; try to repair it.

I searched on google, it says the reason is the folder /tmp is full, I need to delete this folder. But I'm using amazon RDS mysql, how can I logon the server to delete the folder?